# How to get input from a webservice

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

I am trying to write a program that will receive an input from a web service and select the correct information that goes along with the order ID. I am using xPath for this as it is required. For example, if I enter a 1 under the OrderID when I run the program it should pull the totalcost for that order and display it. I know there is definitely something wrong with my code, since I am new to this I have no idea how to physically grab an input when I have no control of the variables being used. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Here is my code:

```
[WebMethod]
public int GetTotalCostForAnOrder(int OrderID)
{
    XPathNavigator nav;
    XPathDocument docNav;
    XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;

    String rootPath = Server.MapPath("~");
    string strFilename = rootPath + "\\OrderInfoLab3.xml";
    docNav = new XPathDocument(strFilename);

    // Create a navigator to query with XPath.
    nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
    String searchString = "sum(OrderFeed/Order/Items/Item/TotalCost)";

    // you need to determine the proper XPath statement

    // Select the node and place the results in an iterator.
    NodeIter = nav.Select(searchString);

    while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
    {
        NodeIter.Current.Select("OrderID");
    }

    var totalOrder = nav.Compile(searchString);
    return Convert.ToInt32(nav.Evaluate(totalOrder));
}
```

Here is my XML File:

```
<Order id="1">
<BillingInformation>
    <Name>Bruce Ganek</Name>
    <Address>99 Main Street</Address>
    <City>Cranston</City>
    <State>RI</State>
    <ZipCode>02910</ZipCode>
</BillingInformation>
<ShippingInformation>
    <Name>Governor Chafee</Name>
    <Address>82 Smith St # 115</Address>
    <City>Providence</City>
    <State>RI</State>
    <ZipCode>02903-1121</ZipCode>
</ShippingInformation>
<Items>
    <Item>
        <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo>
        <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description>
        <UnitPrice>10.50</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <TotalCost>21.00</TotalCost>
        <CustomerOptions>
            <Size>M</Size>
            <Color>Green</Color>
        </CustomerOptions>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <PartNo>JETSWEATER</PartNo>
        <Description>N.Y. Jets Sweatshirt</Description>
        <UnitPrice>7.50</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>3</Quantity>
        <TotalCost>22.50</TotalCost>

        <CustomerOptions>
            <Size>S</Size>
            <Color>White</Color>
        </CustomerOptions>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <PartNo>JETSFLASHLIGHT</PartNo>
        <Description>N.Y. Jets Flashlight</Description>
        <UnitPrice>5.00</UnitPrice>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <TotalCost>5.00</TotalCost>

        <CustomerOptions/>

    </Item>

</Items>
</Order>
```

Here is the error I get in my output:

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.
at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select(XPathExpression expr)
at System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator.Select(String xpath)
at Lab3.Service1.GetTotalCostForAnOrder(Int32 OrderID) in C:\
```

Comment: your method is returning an int..it should be decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use LINQ2XML

```
public decimal GetTotalCostForAnOrder(int OrderID)
{
    XElement doc=XElement.Load("c:\\yourXML.xml");
    decimal totalPrice=doc.DescendantsAndSelf("Order")
    .Where(x=>x.Attribute("id").Value==OrderID)
    .Select(y=>y.Element("Items")).Elements("Item")
    .Select(z=>decimal.Parse(z.Element("TotalCost").Value)).ToList().Sum();
    return totalPrice;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this seems to be a much easier way to iterate through my XML file without having to use defined paths. My only problem is I want to return a string of all items for an order (still by the OrderID). I tried just adding the .ToList() at the end of the 'y' variable line, and returning that but for some reason it only returns an instance of the list object itself. Any suggestions?

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]'

Comment: @nate00234 if you want all values of the order int a string use `y=>y.Element("Items")).Elements("Item").Value`

Answer (score 2):

The following line appears to be incorrect:

```
String searchString = "sum(OrderFeed/Order/Items/Item/TotalCost)";
```

This is supposed to be the XPath expression to select the nodes, but there is no `OrderFeed` node in your XML - the root node is `Order`.

This should bring better results as a node collection:

```
String searchString = "/Order/Items/Item/TotalCost";
```

Comment: But would that selection sum up the value of total cost for each item when evaluated?

Comment: @nate - no it will not. But you first need to get the path right.

Comment: My fault I forgot to add the root node, it actually does start with OrderFeed